# Create bootable backup image of my Win08 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines

Running WinServer 08 - Web edition SP2. I'd like to create a backup of the system to guard against the various situations where the only solution is to 're-install windows'. Windows 7 has Virtual PC - is this an option for Server08?

Comment: Virtual PC is a virtual machine hypervisor, not a backup solution; I'm a little confused as to what you're asking after seeing VPC thrown in there. You just want to know how to back up the server? There are tons of backup solutions available.

Comment: I'm dating myself. Backup used to mean just data. Wasn't aware MS had implemented a bootable system backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [built-in Backup tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770266(WS.10).aspx), it will do bare-metal restore and is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

or use disk2vhd, then in a strange way windows 7 with virtual pc would kinda work!